# Full Text Search SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have implemented Full text search, and I have created some stop words like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and other are default.

I am using this function CONTAINSTABLE(Employee, *, '"0007*"',1033) and I am taking only 10 records at first so when i run this i got records other then 0007 and I got 0007 on 40 row.

So i want at the first position whatever is the exact match it comes first and other are coming after that.

I do not want to use weight term.Please advise me how to achieve this.

thanks,
Keyur

Comment: please help me if anyone has idea

Comment: Please help me,still i did not found any